# C++ Splitting list in O(n) instead of O(1)

Tags: c++, list, time-complexity

I am implementing list in c++ and I have problem with complexity of split method. Instead of constant time complexity, my complexity is linear( O(n)).Here is my code:

```
     /*
        * Destructively splits the list into the two that are returned.
        * The first list consists of elements formerly in the [begin, place) range.
        * The second list consists of elements formerly in the [place, end) range.
        */
        std::pair<list, list> list::split(list::const_iterator place) {
            list first_list{}, second_list{};
            if (head == nullptr) {
                return{ first_list, second_list };
            }
            if (head == place.current_ptr) {
                swap(second_list);
                return{ first_list, second_list };
            }
            if (place.current_ptr == nullptr) {
                swap(first_list);
                return{ first_list, second_list };
            }
            first_list.head = head;
            first_list.num_elements = std::distance(cbegin(), place);
            first_list.tail = place.current_ptr->prev;

            second_list.head = place.current_ptr;
            if (second_list.head == nullptr) {
                second_list.tail = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            second_list.head->prev = nullptr;
            second_list.tail = tail;
        }
        second_list.num_elements = num_elements - first_list.num_elements;
        first_list.tail->next = nullptr;

        tail = head = nullptr;
        num_elements = 0;

        return{ first_list, second_list };
    }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Why is your complexity linear?  I see no loop or recursion.

Comment: Well, that's expected if you store the size. `std::list::splice` is known to have the same kind of O(n) complexity problem, which is actually why Boost's `list::splice` has an overload which takes an additional `size` parameter to avoid the O(n) cost of `std::distance`. You could provide a similar overload to partially solve your problem.

Comment: You could also not store the size, but then your list's `size` complexity would become O(n). You've got to make a choice, there is no silver bullet.

Comment: The problem is that split takes linear time equaled to length of the list and not the position where I'm splitting. I want to accomplish that when list with length 50 or 500 000 get splitted after 10th element the time should be the same because I anly need to iterate to 10th element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. `std::pair` created copy of the two lists I was returning so that was what took the linear time. When I `std::move` lists to the pair, it runs in time equal where I'm splitting.